# Rails Routes - SEO for Products and Categories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, seo, routes

today I have URIs like /products/:permalink to show products. Each product has one category and I would like to get something better for SEO as the term "products" is not good for me.

My wish is get "/:category/:permalink" => "/sports/permalink-of-my-product".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that someone knows more than Google. Here's their [guide to SEO](http://www.google.com/webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf). It says:

> Creating descriptive categories and filenames for the documents on
> your website can not only help you keep your site better organized,
> but **it could also lead to better *crawling* of your documents by search
> engines**.

By the way, look at the path to the SEO guide:

> http://www.google.com/webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf

Totally follows this recommendation!